# Postgres выбрать строки, имеющие определенные значения в другой таблице

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, join, backend

products

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Iphone X |
| 2 | Samsung |
| 3 | Xiaomi |
| 4 | Huawei |

products_description

| product_id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 64gb |
| 1 | White |
| 1 | New |
| 2 | 128gb |
| 2 | Black |
| 3 | 64gb |
| 3 | Black |
| 4 | 64gb |
| 4 | Black |

Необходимо выбрать все телефоны, имеющие характеристику "64gb" и "Black" одновременно (результат: Xiaomi, Huawei)

Пример неправильно работающего запроса:
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN products_description ON products.id=products_description.product_id WHERE products_info.description='64gb' AND products_info.description='Black'
(понимаю, что одной той же строки не может быть два разных значения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяй LEFT на INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM products
    INNER JOIN products_info ON products.id = products_info.id
WHERE products_info.description = 'Black' AND products.id IN (SELECT id FROM products INNER JOIN products_info ON products.id = products_info.id WHERE products_info.description = '64gb')
```

Comment: проверил, не работает :-(

Comment: Пришли скрин результата

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Uz5tj26eKB36Uv9HA   схема таблицы и описание несколько иное, но суть та же

Comment: У тебя один столбец имеет только одно значение, а не два, поэтому код не работает, есть вариант либо поменять AND на OR, либо изменить структуру таблицы, либо сделать запрос со вложенным подзапросом

Comment: @MaxZhovtaniuk Изменил ответ, посмотри

Comment: да, спасибо, это действительно работает, но насколько я понимаю это не будет работать, если у меня будет другое количество значений для фильтации

Comment: В примере два фильтра, можно написать код для трех фильтров немного его изменив добавив ... products.id IN (фильтр1) AND products.id IN (фильтр 2) AND ... Возможно есть решение лучше, но пока только это

Comment: В любом случае большое спасибо. Возможно подумаю над осуществлением фильтрации по другому

Comment: Если ответ помог, то проголосуйте "за" или отметьте как решение :)